# Force a column to take full width within a specific window width range

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using the [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) framework and currently have the following structure with 3 content columns inside a row:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4"> <!-- 1st column -->
            <div class="icon-block z-depth-2">
                <h2 class="center red-text"><i class="mdi-action-description"></i></h2>
                <h5 class="center">Content Title 1</h5>
                <p class="light"> content Text 1 </p>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- 1st column  end -->

        <div class="col s12 m4"> <!-- 2nd column -->
            <div class="icon-block z-depth-2">
                <h2 class="center red-text"><i class="mdi-action-settings"></i></h2>
                <h5 class="center">Content Title 2</h5>
                <p class="light"> content Text 2 </p>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- 2nd column end -->

        <div class="col s12 m4"> <!-- 3rd column -->
            <div class="icon-block z-depth-2">
                 <h2 class="center red-text"><i class="mdi-action-help"></i></h2>
                <h5 class="center">Content Title 3</h5>
                <p class="light"> content Text 3 </p>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- 3rd column end -->
    </div>  <!-- row end -->
  </div>  <!-- section end -->
</div> <!-- container end -->
```

While experimenting around I found out that those columns start to order themselves under each other (vertical layout) on a desktop device when the window width is `587px` or less, but I guess those might be (and likely are) some percent values. I was unable to find anything related in the `materializecss` code by searching for related classes and viewing their attributes.

The question: **how can I modify the width from which those columns start to stack vertically?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the `min-width` attribute. But I would create a custom class and then override it. Below is an example for your current code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .row .col.m4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

[image]

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/c40y5o3a/2/)

Comment: well, what I need is to say "starting with a window width of XXX, the columns should become stacked vertically AND each column should take its `max-width`". Declaring a `min-width` causes (for example) 2 columns beside each other and 1 column below them.

Comment: Checkout my update. It does work from here. Not the 2 column + 1 beneath.

Comment: accepting 'cause you got me thinking the right direction, thx. I ended up with `@media only screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 1600px)` and setting the `.row .col.m4` width to 100% which forces the column to take the whole container width and the other columns to go below it on sizes 250 to 1600px

Comment: Oh I see. You could have reframed the question as 'Forcing the column to occupy full width within specific browser size'. Would have been simple for me and the other answerer :)

Comment: oh well.. my original question was as stated but your answer made me understand that I actually have to make it occupy the full width to achieve what I need ;)

Answer (score 1):

Materialize provide `sass` so if you know how to work with it you can easily modify those values.

Take a look at the following snippet at `sass/components/_grid.scss file`
which is responsible for the `css` of the grid (and therefore also the width of `container`,`col`,`row`,`sX`, etc. elements):

```
  .col {
float: left;
@include box-sizing(border-box);
padding: 0 $gutter-width / 2;

$i: 1;
@while $i <= $num-cols {
  $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
  &.s#{$i} {
    width: $perc;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  $i: $i + 1;
}
$i: 1;
@while $i <= $num-cols {
  $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
  &.offset-s#{$i} {
    margin-left: $perc;
  }
  $i: $i + 1;
}

@media #{$medium-and-up} {

  $i: 1;
  @while $i <= $num-cols {
    $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
    &.m#{$i} {
      width: $perc;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
  }
  $i: 1;
  @while $i <= $num-cols {
    $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
    &.offset-m#{$i} {
      margin-left: $perc;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
  }

}

@media #{$large-and-up} {

  $i: 1;
  @while $i <= $num-cols {
    $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
    &.l#{$i} {
      width: $perc;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
  }
  $i: 1;
  @while $i <= $num-cols {
    $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
    &.offset-l#{$i} {
      margin-left: $perc;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
  }

}
```

As you can see there are several `min-width` queries and the related variables are being set at `_variable.scss`:

```
// Media Query Ranges
$small-screen-up: 601px !default;
$medium-screen-up: 993px !default;
$large-screen-up: 1201px !default;
$small-screen: 600px !default;
$medium-screen: 992px !default;
$large-screen: 1200px !default;
```

You can simply change the values according to your desire and "compile" it to css.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that so I'm looking for a css/js solution to the problem